# No qualifying bean of type 'ru.spb.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, web-services, configuration

Repository class:

```
 package ru.spb.repository.user;

@Repository
public class AnketUserRepository implements UserRepository {

     @Autowired
     private CrudUserRepository crudRepository;

 }
```

Interface:

```
package ru.spb.repository;

public interface UserRepository {
}
```

Service:

```
package ru.spb.service;

@Service
public class UserService {

   private final UserRepository repository;

   @Autowired
   public UserService (UserRepository repository){
       this.repository = repository;
   }
}
```

Configs:
in spring-app.xml:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.service"/>
```

in spring-db.xml:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.repository.user"/>
```

But I catch the following exception:

```
 NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.spb.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I tried to add @Repository on UserRepository-interface, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.repository.user"/>
```

from spring-db.xml  to  spring-app.xml.   And this problem is solved.
However I dont understand the reason of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Annotate the Interface also

```
package ru.spb.repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
}
```

Comment: I done this now and earlier, with with the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Your component scan is configured only to the package of the implementing class, but you are autowiring the interface which is on a different (non component scanned) package.
Move the `@Repository` annotation to the inteface, and add `ru.spb.repository` to your component-scan

Comment: I add @Repository annotation to the inteface, and add ru.spb.repository to my component-scan.  But I catch the same exception...